# Make io.Copy interruptible to send data to stream in chunks every n seconds?

Tags: go, tcp, io

I have this code:

```
for { // infinite loop
    // connect
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", forward_ip_port)
    if L.IsError(err, `Failed to connect to `+forward_ip_port) {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        continue
    }
    // TODO: query 100 data from last one, translate to string
    arr := PG.QStrArr(`
    SELECT x1.id || '#' || x1.data -- *snip, some other column*
    FROM station_logs x1
    WHERE x1.id > ` + I.ToS(last_id) + ` 
    ORDER BY x1.id 
    LIMIT ` + I.ToS(limit))
    if len(arr) == 0 {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        continue
    }
    // write to server
    fmt.Println(`Start sending ` + I.ToStr(len(arr)) + ` records`)
    for _, txt := range arr {
        n, err := fmt.Fprintf(conn, txt+"\r\n")
        L.IsError(err, `Failed to deliver `+txt)
        fmt.Print(txt)
        fmt.Println(` ` + I.ToStr(n) + ` bytes written`)
    }
    //L.IsError(conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second*3)), `Failed to set deadline`)
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, conn)
    // close connection
    conn.Close()
    // write last id to file
    last := arr[len(arr)-1]
    last = S.LeftOf(last, `#`)
    last_id := S.ToI(last)
    last_id_str := I.ToS(last_id)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(last_id_file, []byte(last_id_str), 0644)
    L.IsError(err, `Failed to write `+last_id_str+` to `+last_id_file)
    // sleep for 1 seconds
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

The purpose of this code is to deliver data to server, with interval of 1 second. The server will reply line-by-line (similar to echo server) and wait for next line of items, and will never close the connection.

The problem with code above is, I could not interrupt the `io.Copy` to disconnect or resume sending next batch.

What's better way to do this?

Comment: The only way to interrupt the blocking Read in the Copy is to set a deadline, or close the connection. What is the problem with the SetReadDeadline solution?

Comment: Mentioning a delay always smells bad. What real problem are you trying to solve? Maybe you should just need to collect bits of data to be sent in small batches and require each of them to be ACKed by the server? In other words, please try to explain where the requirement to have an "interval of 1 second" came from, as otherwise it looks like a manifestation of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: i need to transfer a bunch of data to another server without giving them high spike on CPU usage, actually the data itself already converted into a table, and i need to transfer back using the old format that i received before, and send it to another server --> the boss asked this instead of binary replication so he can use another vendor that can read compatible format instead of my software

Comment: @JimB `SetReadDeadline` works perfectly, apparently it's my mistake shadowing `last_id` variable

Comment: @Kokizzu please always use `@username` when you're replying to someone's comment to have them notified--otherwise your reply gets effectively lost, as has happened to yours :-(

Comment: @Kokizzu, OK back to the essense of the question: I actually fail to parse your problem statement so let's consider this from another angle. Is it possible to implement "chunking" of data on your side? Say, you read *and buffer* some number of rows from the result of your query, then send it out, then wait. You could record the time instant the server ACK'ed your chunk so you know how much time to wait.

Comment: @Kokizzu it has a drawback of having to buffer the data before sending, but your could implement sort of streaming by creating a buffered channel--having the capacity equal to the size of a single chunk--and having a goroutine `range`-ing over the channel and sending the rows it gets from it right away; the goroutine which consumes the data from the query results closes the channel when it's done with the chunk so the sending goroutine knows the chunk is over and quits. Variations are possible but I hope the general idea should be clear.

Comment: @kostix yeah, but i have no idea how to implement the channel stuff (not enough knowledge for now)